# Tesseract api delete

Tags: c++, visual-studio, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Программа ругается на **delete api**; Код взят от [сюда](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/APIExample). Пишет **Программа вызвал срабатывание точки останова.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//include tesseract headers
#include <baseapi.h>
#include <allheaders.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix* image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete api;
    delete[] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1155277/398802

Comment: Если есть проблемы со сторонним кодом, то можно запостить issue на их гитхабе